# Function for approximating the definite integral of a function using an r-degree polynomial

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, approximation, approximate-integration

We have the **Midpoint Rule** which approximates the definite integral of a function $f(x)$ over $[a, b]$ using $n$ sub-intervals with width $\Delta x$ using a degree-0 polynomial $A$:

$$\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)dx}\ \approx \Delta x \Big[ f(\frac{x_0 + x_1}{2}\ ) 
 + f(\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}\ )
 + ... + f(\frac{x_{n-1} + x_n}{2}\ )\Big]$$

We also have the **Trapezoid Rule**, which does the same, but with a degree-1 polynomial $Ax + B$:

$$\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)dx}\ \approx \frac{\Delta x}{2}\ \Big[ f(x_0) 
 + 2f(x_1)
 + ... 
 + 2f(x_{n-1})
 + f(x_n)\Big]$$

Finally we have **Simpson's Rule**, which uses a degree-2 polynomial $A{x^2} + Bx + C$:

$$\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)dx}\ \approx \frac{\Delta x}{3}\ \Big[ f(x_0) 
 + 4f(x_1)
 + 2f(x_2)
 + ... 
 + 2f(x_{n-2})
 + 4f(x_{n-1})
 + f(x_n)\Big]$$

This begs the question, is there a function $g(r)$ that approximates the definite integral of a function $f(x)$ over $[a, b]$ using $n$ sub-intervals of width $\Delta x$ using an $r$-degree polynomial?

Ex.

$$g(1) = \frac{\Delta x}{2}\ \Big[ f(x_0) 
 + 2f(x_1)
 + ... 
 + 2f(x_{n-1})
 + f(x_n)\Big]$$
$$g(2) = \frac{\Delta x}{3}\ \Big[ f(x_0) 
 + 4f(x_1)
 + 2f(x_2)
 + ... 
 + 2f(x_{n-2})
 + 4f(x_{n-1})
 + f(x_n)\Big]$$
$$g(r) = ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: these are called [Newton–Cotes formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cotes_formulas). However, they are rather unstable at higher degrees and hence not much used. You get the weights by integrating the [Lagrange interpolation polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.